# Retrieve my adsense report as server application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, adsense, adsense-api

All I need is like so,

1. I want to use Ruby and Google API to retrieve MY adsense report (like page views, CTR ...) and save it into my database. (I want it to be automatic)
2. When an user requests to my page, I will show my saved report to him.

I think it was simple but it's not actually because OAuth 2.0 needs users to authenticate with google. I dont know how I can do it because I dont have any browsers on my server. Is it possible to do so? Can anyone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The AdSense Management API can be used with the "Installed application" OAuth2 scenario. You just need to generate the refresh token once (you don't need browsers on your server and no human interaction is needed after this).

Here's the generic guide:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started#auth

And the Ruby client library, with the adsense sample:
https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/tree/master/adsense

The client library handles auth for you.